# Notification for comment upvotes

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I have noticed that when I leave comments on a question and someone votes it up, I do not get a notification. If the upvote count would at least be more than 5, I would expect to be notified since that leads to a badge.

Comment: Is it really important to be notified in case of a *comment* upvote? I don't see the point...

Comment: @Pekka: I'm sure you do. +1

Comment: Please no, that would be far too much noise. Well, for others. Nobody ever upvotes my comments. Still though, comments aren't really all that important within SO/SE and I don't need to get notified each time someone simply thinks it's a good comment.

Comment: @Pekka You mean aside from social validation of my witty remarks? Though I guess we already have a badge for that

Comment: If you are going for Pundit badge you can check your upvoted comments like this: `api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/751527/comments?sort=votes&min=5`

Comment: @pekka, I expect it to notify if the vote count more than 5. Since it leads to a badge.

Comment: Please stop posting if you people think this question is not a question. I have already flagged it to close. thank you for this much downvotes. I just ask for clarification and it was just my expectation.

Comment: Why would we have to stop posting? And [sometimes on Meta downvotes are used to indicate disagreement with an idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), rather than that your question is a bad one. Don't worry about it. Meta rep won't buy you anything anyway. And there's no need to close this question.

Comment: Well from now i am not interested in buying one if asked for :)

Comment: Oh wait, you guys didn't get notified that I upvoted your comments, so I'm leaving this comment to let you know that I upvoted your comments. Mmmkay?

Comment: <sarcasm>Aaaaand I'm out.</sarcasm> :-) +1 by the way

Comment: @juergend That beautiful line seem to not work anymore. Is there a way to update it to the new api?

Comment: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2088676//comments?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=votes

Answer (score 14):

Comments are not first class citizens:

- you can't downvote them.
- only moderators can edit them and there is no edit trail left.
- you won't get any reputation for the comments.
- you won't get any notification if a comment is changed.

The reason for this is this is a Question and Answer site. Comments are a way to comment or ask for clarification.

Comment: I would however like a nice way to see if any of my comments get upvoted, even if that means just showing a number on my comments in the activity tab.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow does not provide this feature, probably because most would consider that notification to be overkill. I agree with that decision. Comments get upvoted a *lot*.

Comment: So make it opt-in.

Comment: Or, if not a notification, at least there should be a section or link on my profile/account page to such information.

Answer (score 5):

Comment notifications would be noisy for most users as noted in other answers, but if your goal is to track those badges, you could use [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/484281/pundit-comments-with-scores-sorted-desc).  SEDE data is refreshed weekly, so this won't be *completely* up to date, but for long-haul badges like Pundit, it's still helpful.

Besides, when you get that badge, aren't you a little curious about *which* comments were popular?  Instead of digging through notifications one upvote at a time, just ask the data.